# iOS: Building project from terminal using xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, command-line, compiler-errors, static-libraries, xcodebuild

I have a static library in the project. I have setup `header search path` correctly to point library directory `recursively`. Could someone please tell me why is following error while buling project from terminal using `xcodebuild`?

> ```
> admin$ xcodebuild install DSTROOT=. INSTALL_PATH=/bin
>
> /Users/admin/iNewsArticle.h:11:9: fatal error: 'XPathQuery/TFHpple.h' file not found
> #import <XPathQuery/TFHpple.h>
>         ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

[EDIT]

If you getting this error; see my other related post - [iOS: Absolute project path with xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569402/ios-absolute-project-path-with-xcodebuild/16569537?noredirect=1#16569537) for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
#import "XPathQuery/TFHpple.h"
```

The angle-brackets are used by the system search paths (basically whatever frameworks you have included)....  if you have a recursive header search path you may also just be able to use:

```
#import "TFHpple.h"
```

Comment: Thanks Kendall. I thought same that there is something wrong with angle-brackets and quoted includes but it didn't make any difference. I basically linked each library so angle-brackets works fine without worrying about "Header Search Path" but when I ran this command from terminal, after this error, I tried setting "header search path" and also tried using quoted inclusions but no help. I researched more on compilation messages on XCode and noticed that sub projects also compiled from root project so I ran same command from the root project directory and it worked!!