# iOS: Absolute project path with xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, compilation, terminal, build-automation, xcodebuild

I use following command to build project using `xcodebuild` from the directory where .xcodeproj is.

```
admin$ xcodebuild install DSTROOT=. INSTALL_PATH=/bin
```

Could someone please tell me how to specify full path of .xcodeproj in `xcodebuild` command and run it from anywhere?

[EDIT]

...so you cannot specify absolute path of the project with xcodebuild command but you can specify where do you want your .app file placed like following. You need to run this command from the root project directory and you will be able to compile other sub projects without CD to their directories but you need to specify "scheme" that you are building.

```
admin$ xcodebuild install DSTROOT=/Users/admin/myProjectRoot INSTALL_PATH=/bin -scheme MySubProject1 -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator clean build
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the manpage for xcodebuild](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html), you *must* launch "`xcodebuild`" from within the directory where your project is.  I.E. the specific line that clarifies that is:

> To build an Xcode project, run xcodebuild from the directory
>   containing your project (i.e. the directory containing the
>   projectname.xcodeproj package).

And if there are multiple projects within that directory, that's when you can use the "`-project projectname`" command line parameter.

In my own build scripts, I "`cd`" to the folder where the project lives before calling "`xcodebuild`".

Comment: Thanks Michael! Now I am running this command from the root project's folder and able to provide "scheme" for various other projects.